# Drag and drop file onto console application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, console-application

I am trying to create a Console Application in Visual Studio using C# to be able to drag and drop a .txt file onto the .exe file and have it find and replace within that file. Eventually I also want it to then save-as with _unwrapped at the end of the original file-name. I am very new to C# and this is what I have so far. It works on the test file I have placed in the debug folder. How do I make this work with a dragged file? I tried a few things I found on google but they did not work and I did not understand them. Thank you!!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string text = File.ReadAllText("test.txt");
            text = text.Replace("~", "~\r\n");
            File.WriteAllText("test.txt", text);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do a google search on the following and see what results you find 
`C# Drag and drop file onto console application` perhaps you should consider doing this in a `Wnforms` application you may have better success

Comment: @MethodMan She does not want to drop it on the window, just on the exe

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you drag a file on an .exe in Windows, the .exe will be executed with the file's path as its argument. You only have to extract the argument from the `args` parameter:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
    if (args.Length == 0)
       return; // return if no file was dragged onto exe
    string text = File.ReadAllText(args[0]);
    text = text.Replace("~", "~\r\n");
    string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(args[0]) 
       + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar 
       + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(args[0]) 
       + "_unwrapped" + Path.GetExtension(args[0]);
    File.WriteAllText(path, text);

 }
```

Comment: Would this then create a file named test.txt in the debug folder? if so it will not work for me.

Comment: @Emmily I edited my answer. Now it will have the behavior you desired.

Comment: you are my hero! Thank you so much!