# Parse the file fullpath and name into c# console app

Tags: c#, file, parsing, powerpoint

I try to implement an app which would allow me to convert a PPT or PPTX files into jpgs and I plan to use it globally on my pc. The problem I am facing is that I don't know how to parse the file I open in the app. Basically I need the app to get the fullpath and filename when I open a specific file so hardcoding some specific route is out of question.

General idea: I take a ppt file and drag it onto the .exe file then it processes the ppt file and in the end i have a folder with all the jpgs in the same place as the ppt. This is what I have so far:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Core;
using System;
using PowerPoint = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;

namespace PPInterop
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            

            var app = new PowerPoint.Application();

            var pres = app.Presentations;

            var file = pres.Open(@"C:\presentation1.jpg", MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoFalse);

            file.SaveCopyAs(@"C:\presentation1.jpg", PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsJPG, MsoTriState.msoTrue);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You see that parameter to your Main function named `args`?

Comment: Yes, I do. I'd like some clarifications if that's possible

Comment: `args` should contain the full path to the file you dragged to the exe. You'll have to parse that to find the folder.  Use the `System.IO.Path` class

Comment: don't you want to access each slide an export it separately, though?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want but I guess file.SaveCopyAs already does that. I tested it with the hardcoded path and it put all of the jpgs in the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning the parsing I think you've already found Microsoft's way to do this by using code from `Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint`.

But you're loading a JPG instead of a PPT or PPTX file. Drag & drop should also be possible by using `args` as (at least Windows) will run the application with the dragged file as argument (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37124819/drag-and-drop-file-onto-console-application)).

So I think could be something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length == 0)
        throw new Exception("No presentation file given");

    var presentationFilePath = new FileInfo(args[0]);

    if (presentationFilePath.Exists == false)
        throw new FileNotFoundException("No presentation given");

    var app = new PowerPoint.Application();
    var presentation = app.Presentations.Open(presentationFilePath, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoFalse);
    var jpgName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(presentationFilePath.FullName) + ".jpg";
    presentation.SaveCopyAs(jpgName, PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsJPG, MsoTriState.msoTrue);

    Console.WriteLine("Converted " + presentationFilePath + " to " + jpgName);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo with the parsed jpg file. I just play around with the code trying to figure out. Forgot to correct it. RIght now I am trying to do this using args of the Main method.

Comment: Thanks for nudging me in the right direction